# PHP Client error during OpenSearch reIndex() operation

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an Amazon OpenSearch Service set up. I am using the: `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch"` version 7.17.2 in my Laravel php service to create a client. I am aware this is the wrong client to use for OpenSearch but it should be compatible and we have just switched to OpenSearch and have yet to switch the client as it would not be easy in this particular code base.

I am trying to run a reIndex() to fix a complicated error where that led to one of my indexes experiencing a mapping explosion (over 1000 field mappings) the reIndex function has a small painless script in the parameters to change the format of the problem field from an object to a nested field and changes the field mappings appropriately.

I have taken a snapshot of the Indices on aws and restored them into a locally running docker container that is running the same version of OpenSearch. My reIndex operation runs successfully locally in my docker containers albeit with high cpu usage.

when I try run the same operation on the aws services I have set up I get the following error:

```
     production.ERROR: No alive nodes found in your cluster {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\NoNodesAvailableException(code: 0): No alive nodes found in your cluster at /var/www/html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:64)"} []


In StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php line 64:
                                        
  No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

I have noticed very high cpu and memory usage in the aws OpenSearch cluster during the operation ( >95% ) could this high resource usage explain why my client perceives the OpenSearch cluster as non-responsive? The error only occurs towards the end of the operation as the new index that is created has nearly the same number of lucene docs however the operation stops short as an alias switch that I have set up to run consequently never happens.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was **YES**. I upgraded my OpenSearch service from a m6g.large.search to an m6g.2xlarge.search and the reIndex ran successfully without the php service thinking all the nodes were down in the cluster.